# Django FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have these three tables

```
 class IdentificationAddress(models.Model):
     id_ident_address = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     ident = models.ForeignKey('Ident', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ident')
     address = models.TextField()
     time = models.DateTimeField()

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'identification_address'


 class IdentC(models.Model):
     id_ident = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     ident = models.TextField(unique=True)
     name = models.TextField()

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'ident_c'

class location(models.Model):
    id_ident_loc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ident = models.ForeignKey('IdentC', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ident')
    loc_name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'location
```

I want to get the last 
 *address* field (It could be zero) from *IdentificationAddress* model, the last _loc_name_ field (it matches at least one) from *location* model, *name* field (Only one) from *IdentC* model and *ident* field. The search is base on *ident* field.
I have been reading about many_to_many relationships and prefetch_related. But, they don't seem to be the best way to get these information.

If a use SQL syntax, this instruction does the job:

```
SELECT ident_c.name, ident_c.ident, identification_address.address, location.loc_name FROM  identn_c FULL OUTER JOIN location ON  ident_c.ident=location.ident  FULL OUTER JOIN identification_address ON  ident_c.ident=identification_address.ident;
```

or for this case

```
SELECT ident_c.name, ident_c.ident, identification_address.address, location.loc_name FROM  identn_c LEFT JOIN location ON  ident_c.ident=location.ident  LEFT JOIN identification_address ON  ident_c.ident=identification_address.ident;
```

Based on my little understanding of Django, JOIN instructions cannot be implemented. Hope I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Django ORM take care of it if you set relationship between models.

for example,

models.py

```
class Aexample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Bexample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fkexample = models.ForeignKey(Aexample)
```

shell

```
examplequery = Bexample.objects.filter(fkexample__name="hellothere")
```

SQL query

```
SELECT 
"yourtable_bexample"."id",
"yourtable_bexample"."name",
"yourtable_bexample"."fkexample_id" 
FROM "yourtable_bexample" 
INNER JOIN "yourtable_aexample" 
ON ("yourtable_bexample"."fkexample_id" = "yourtable_aexample"."id") 
WHERE "yourtable_aexample"."name" = hellothere
```

you want to make query in Django like below

```
SELECT ident_c.name, ident_c.ident, identification_address.address, location.loc_name 
FROM  identn_c 
LEFT JOIN location ON  ident_c.ident=location.ident  
LEFT JOIN identification_address ON  ident_c.ident=identification_address.ident;
```

It means you want all rows from identn_c, right?. If you make proper relationship between your tables for your purpose, Django ORM takes care of it.

```
class IntentC(model.Model):
    exampleA = models.ForeignKey(ExampleA)
    exampleB = models.ForeignKey(ExampleB)
```

this command make query with JOIN Clause.

```
identn_instance = IdentC.objects.get(id=somenumber)
identn_instance.exampleA
identn_instance.exampleB
```

you can show every IntentC rows and relating rows in different tables.

```
for in in IntentC.objects.all(): #you can all rows in IntentC
    print(in.exampleA.name) 
    #show name column in exampleA table
    #JOIN ... ON intenctctable.example_id = exampleatable.id 
    print(in.exampleB.name) #show name column in exampleB table / JOIN ... ON
```

Comment: Well, Did you ask that you should use OUTER FULL JOIN? Or Did you ask using WHERE, JOIN Clause in Django in general?

Comment: Hi @Jayground.  In the example model you have as the foreign key the `class Aexample`, my model only have a field inside the class as the foreign key `_ident_`.  The inner join only is going to give me the common data,  I need the full information.  That clause is used in Postgres shell asking `_OUTER_ _FULL_ _JOIN_` that gives me the expected outcome.  For this particular case, `_LEFT_ _JOIN_` is working because of the foreign key.

Comment: I tried the command base on your suggestion for:  `IdentificationAddress.objects.filter(ident__name="00DL")` **error** `ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: text = integer`  `LINE 1: ...ident_c" ON ("identification_address"."ident" = "ident_c...`  `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. `.  Then I tried  `mac_Ip.objects.filter(ident__id_ident='00DL')`  **error** `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00DL'`

Comment: I added more information on my original answer. Please check it. I think you need to make your database structure and relationship first for your purpose in Django ORM. There is a way to use RawQeury. [Check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) please.